# Foreign Key not working in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am creating cms app.

There are two tables - users and posts. Users table have an id of each user. On the other hand, Posts Table has user id which references to the id of users table.

However, while saving the post, I get an error that `Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value`. Why is this? Please help me.

Posts Table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->longText('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}
```

DashboardController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Post;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('dashboard.index');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('dashboard.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $post = new Post();
        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->description = $request->description;
        $post->save();

        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Post model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    //
}
```

User model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'fname', 'lname', 'email', 'password'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }

    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return 'remember_token';
    }
}
```

Although, I defined a foreign key 'user_id', it doesn't automatically fetch the id from user table. How can I fix this?

Comment: The error is because you are not specifying the `user_id` in the save method of the `Post` model.Also the foreign key definition doesn't automatically fetch the `id` from the user table. You should specify which user is related to the post, then you may able to access the related user.

Comment: Thanks, @ab_ab! Understood!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not saving `user_id`:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $post = new Post();
   $post->title = $request->title;
   $post->description = $request->description;
   $post->user_id = Auth::id();
   $post->save();
    
   return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
}
```

Comment: What if I remove foreign key constraint? Will this code work?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to add relations to `Post.php`:

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

And in `User.php`:

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

In `DashboardController` in action `store`:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $post = new Post();
    $post->title = $request->title;
    $post->description = $request->description;

    $user = Auth::user()->id;
    $user->post()->save($post);
    return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
}
```